# Why is my bar plots disappear when scatter plots appear?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I want to display some scatter dots at the right-end edge of the bars and successfully did it, as shown in the Image 1 below.

[image: Image 1]

But when there is only one length of data for the bar chart to draw, the bar disappears or become super thin, so only scatter dot are visible, as shown in Image 2 below.

[image: Image 2]

Then, I disabled the scatter trace and the bars are visible as shown in Image 3 below.

[image: Image 3]

Below are the scripts to produce these plots.

```js
    let initial = new Date("2020-11-08T00:00:00.000Z");
    let final = new Date("2020-12-08T00:00:00.000Z");
    let half = new Date((initial.getTime() + final.getTime())/2);

    Plotly.newPlot(
        testplot, {
            data: [
                { y: [1000], x: [half], type: 'bar', offsetgroup: 0},
                { y: [1000], x: [half], type: 'bar', offsetgroup: 1},
                { y: [250], x: [final]},
            ], layout: { title: 'single bar', bargap: 0}, config: { responsive: true },
        }
    );

    let t0 = initial, t1 = half, t2 = final;
    let h0 = new Date((t0.getTime() + t1.getTime())/2);
    let h1 = new Date((t1.getTime() + t2.getTime())/2);

    Plotly.newPlot(
        testplot2, {
            data: [
                { y: [500, 750], base: [0, 250], x: [h0, h1], type: 'bar', offsetgroup: 0},
                { y: [500, 750], base: [0, 250], x: [h0, h1], type: 'bar', offsetgroup: 1},
                { y: [200, 800], x: [half, final]}
            ], layout: { title: 'more than one bar', bargap: 0 }, config: { responsive: true }
        }
    )
```

Right now, I have to calculate the midpoint of the date myself so I can offset the bars to the left so the dots appear at the right-edge of the bars. If I use the default dates to plot the bars and the dots, the dots will be placed at the center of the bars, but the bar on "single bar" did not disappear, as shown in Image 4 below.

[image: Image 4]

I have no issue when the data length is more than one, but when the length is one; is there any way to make bars filled the canvas and the dot stays at the right edge? or how to offset the dots to the right?